# How to pass List<CustomObject> through Intents

Tags: java, android, list, android-intent, arraylist

I have ArrayList Of Custom Objects

```
ArrayList<AvailableCountry>
        listAvailableCountries = new ArrayList();
```

and I have two objects of AvailableCountry

```
AvailableCountry obj1=new AvailableCountry();
AvailableCountry obj2=new AvailableCountry();
```

Then i have added to arraylist

```
listAvailableCountries.add(obj1);
listAvailableCountries.add(obj2);
```

And this is Class of Custom Object

```
public class AvailableCountry {

@SerializedName("Disabled")
@Expose
private Boolean disabled;
@SerializedName("Selected")
@Expose
private Boolean selected;
@SerializedName("Text")
@Expose
private String text;
@SerializedName("Value")
@Expose
private String value;

public Boolean getDisabled() {
    return disabled;
}

public void setDisabled(Boolean disabled) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
}

public Boolean getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}

}
```

Now i want to pass this arraylist From Activity A to Activity B.
and then i want to receive in Activity B.
how can i achieve this task.

Comment: By letting `AvailableCountry` implement `Parcelable`

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/2141166/6032850

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) First of all implement Serializable interface to your Custom Object Class

```
public class AvailableCountry implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("Disabled")
@Expose
private Boolean disabled;
@SerializedName("Selected")
@Expose
private Boolean selected;
@SerializedName("Text")
@Expose
private String text;
@SerializedName("Value")
@Expose
private String value;

public Boolean getDisabled() {
    return disabled;
}

public void setDisabled(Boolean disabled) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
}

public Boolean getSelected() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(Boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

2) Send the arrayList from your Class A to Class B

```
Intent intent =new Intent(A.this,B.class);
intent.putExtra("listCountry", (Serializable) listAvailableCountries);
startActivity(intent)
```

3) Receive the arraylist in Class B

```
ArrayList<AvailableCountry>listAvailableCountries = (ArrayList<AvailableCountry>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("listCountry");
```

Comment: Please dont forget to mark upvote if my answer is valid.

Comment: You are amazing sir.you saved my day.

Comment: Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

using Gson we can easily share the data

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```

send like this in A.class

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
    String favJSONString = new Gson().toJson(listAvailableCountries);
    intent.putExtra("listAvailableCountries", favJSONString);
    startActivity(intent);
```

and receive like this B.class

```
try {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<AvailableCountry>>() {
        }.getType();
        ArrayList<AvailableCountry> listAvailableCountries  = new Gson().fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("listAvailableCountries"), type);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```